# ブラウザで同じ画面を共有する方法

Tags: javascript, html

ブラウザーで以下のような特徴を持ったWEBサービスがあるのですが、
どのような技術を使えばできるのか、わかりましたら教えて下さい。

知人が作ったウェブサービスですが、当人が音信不通で要素技術がわかりません。

----WEBサービスのイメージ----

ブラウザー上で同じ画面を共有し、
離れた二つのPCで画像やカードなどのオブジェクトの動きを共有します。

画面はキャンバスのようになっており、
画像・カードの配置・移動・リサイズ・削除などが可能です。
※イメージ的にはトランプのように複数のカードが盤面に配置されているように思って下さい。
　それぞれのカードの移動・リサイズ・削除などが可能です。

片方のPCで画像やカードを移動すると、もう一台のPCブラウザー上で
カードの動きがほぼ同時に再現されます。
ただしマウスは相手のPCには表示されません。

移動・リサイズ・削除はほぼ同時に再現されており、タイムラグは殆どありません。
サーバーに情報を上げているのは確実ですが、
いわゆるAjaxだけで相手側のPCでリアルタイムにリロードはできるのでしょうか。

私が感じているのは、リアルタイムにデータベースから画像の座標などをリロードするのは
速度に限界があるのではないかと思います。

サーバーは、一般のレンタルサーバーを使っており、
node.jsのようなサーバー側からのプッシュは使ってないようです。

ちょっと的外れの質問もあるかもしれませんが、
ご回答いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: WEBサービスならソースを見れば何かヒントがありそうです。

Answer (score 5):

全くの的外れかもしれませんが

WebRTCのデータチャネルを使っているのではないでしょうか?

[WebRTCのデータチャネル解説 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/udonchan/items/7f5ffa9e8982ae1636c3)

[WebRTCコトハジメ - Qiita](http://qiita.com/Y-NAKA/items/286f569d110daede721e)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ビンゴでした。
WebRTC peer.js　というのを使い、ブラウザー間で直接通信していました。
ソースの一部にそのようなJSの表記が見つかりました。

とりあえず、おおまかな流れはわかりました。
ヒントをいただき、誠にありがとうございます。